# Fill Factor And Insert Speed

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 3 very large tables with clustered indexes on composite keys.  No updates only inserts.  New inserts will not be within the existing index range but the new inserts will not align with the clustered index and these tables get a lot of inserts (hundreds - thousands per second).  What would like to do is DBREINDEX with Fill Factor = 100 but then set a Fill Factor of 5 and have that Fill Factor ONLY applied to inserts.  Right now a Fill Factor applies to the whole table only.  Is there a way to have a Fill Factor that applies to inserts (or inserts and updates) only?   I don't care about select speed at this time.  I am loading data.  When the data load is complete then I will DBREINDEX at 100.  A Fill Factor of 10 versus 30 doubles the rates at which new data is inserted.  This load will takes a couple days and it cannot go live until the data is loaded. The clustered indexes are aligned with dominate query used by the end user application.

My practice is to DBREINDEX daily but the problem is now that the tables are getting large a 10 DBREINDEX takes a long time.  I have considered indexing into "daily" tables and then inserting that data daily sorted by the clustered index into the production tables.

If you read this far even more.  The indexes are all composite and I am running 6 instances of the parser on an 8 core server (lot of testing and that seems to have the best throughput).  The data out of a SINGLE parser is in PK order and I am doing the inserts 990 values at a time (SQL value limits).  The 3 active tables only share data via a foreign key relationship with a single relative inactive 4th table.   My thought at this time is to have holding tables for each parser and then have another process that polls those table for the next complete insert and move the data into the production table in PK order.  That is going to be a lot of work.  I hope someone has a better idea.

The parses start in PK order but rarely finish in PK order.  Some individual parses are so large that I could not hold all the data in memory until the end.  Right now the SQL insert is slightly faster than the parse that creates the data.  In an individual parse I run the insert asynch and go on parsing but don't insert until the prior insert is complete.

Comment: I agree you should have holding tables for the parser data and only insert to the main tables when you're ready. I implemented something similar in a former life (it was quasi-hashed into 10 tables based on mod 10 of the unique ID, then rolled into the primary table later - primarily to assist in load speed).

Comment: And if you're going to use holding tables then I see no need to have them at anything but FF = 100. The less pages you have to use the better

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks,  On the holding tables strategy one parse may (actually is like to) finish out of order so it will come in under the prior.  If I insert at the end of the parse what should the fill factor be on the production table.  If a table has a fill factor of 100 and there is an incremental page split then is that page split 50?  For me that would be ideal.

Comment: Implemented the holding tables and testing it on the smaller parses with 4 concurrent parse.exe and I will let it run all night.  The big parses is where I expect (hope) a performance gain.

Comment: I am going to try TVP and bypass the #temp.  With #temp insert and select into from #temp SQL is getting hit hard and there is only one SQL so I will try moving more of the load to the parse.exe.

Comment: TVP was the ticket.  TVP is over twice as fast #TEMP.  That limit of 1000 values on an insert made for very chatty app.  #temp was still chatty.  Not 1000 limit on TVP so reduced the number of call by a factor of 100.

Comment: @AaronBertrand if you want to post an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree you should have holding tables for the parser data and only insert to the main tables when you're ready. I implemented something similar in a former life (it was quasi-hashed into 10 tables based on mod 10 of the unique ID, then rolled into the primary table later - primarily to assist in load speed). If you're going to use holding tables then I see no need to have them at anything but FF = 100. The less pages you have to use the better.

Apparently, too, you should test the difference permanent tables, #temp tables and table-valued parameters. :-)